# How to make Array List use for the other Activity

Tags: android, arraylist

I'm newcomer about the Android Studio so need to help from everyone.

I have an idea that, I want to make 1 ArrayList<>, and I will use this Array for the other Activity, but I don't know how to make.

For example MainActivity, I call this array. SecondActivity, I also call this array. In this case, I no need to make the same ArrayList for each Activity.

Is it possible to do like that? Please help

```js
Example(); //I want to insert this to the other Activity instead of private void...
     test.setOnClick...

private void Example(){
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.add(...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use from this:

In first activity (for example MyActivity) :

```
public static ArrayList<String> myList=new ArrayList();
```

in other activity

```
MyActivity.myList.add("dddd");
MyActivity.myList.get(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

May be this question is duplicate but as you are new contributor and as per Stack Overflow policy i am telling you!

There are Different ways you can use them accordingly..

1- Make list static and use it anywhere with class reference like `MainActivity.list;`

2- Pass in your Intent as `intent.putExtra("en", list);` 
but be sure that you implemented Serializable in your model as

```
 public class EN implements Serializable {
  //Your Model Getter setters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Singleton pattern to share variable between your Activity.

```
public class AppData {
    private List list;
    private static AppData instance;

    private AppData(){};
    public List getList() {return this.list;}
    public void setList(List list) {this.list = list;}

    public static AppData getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
             instance = new AppData();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
//Call this in your activity
List list = AppData.getInstace().getList();
```